# Why Django's OneToOneField returns 500 if relation aready exists

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In a Django REST Framework POST view, is there any way to avoid an **HTTP 500** if the OneToOneField relation already exists?

Instead, it would be great to get an **HTTP 400**.

**models.py**

```
class Club(TimeStampModel):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['owner', 'active']
```

**views.py**

```
class ClubRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please share code of your models, serializers and view\viewsets

Comment: ok, question updated!

Answer (score 1):

When you passed `owner` like this `serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)` serializer doesn't perform validation. You should rewrite `create` instead of `perform_create` method for this

```
class ClubRegistrationView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data["owner"] = request.user.pk
        return super().create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here a validation error:

```
{'user': ['This field must be unique.']}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. Django raises exception "AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable"

Comment: @PolRodoreda Before the `request.data["owner"] = ` line try `request.data = request.data.copy()`